# Why derivative cannot be zero at some point in the interval given with the given constraints?

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f(x)$ (0,$\infty$) -> $(0,\infty)$  which is continuously differentiable (single) and satisfies  that $f(f(x)) = 2x$ why its not possible for $f'(x)$ to be zero somewhere ? even though i got that $f'(f(x)) f'(x) = 2$ but why can we definitely say that $f'(x)$ cannot be zero at any point on $(0,\infty)$ is it because $f'(f(x))$ cannot be infinity at any point ,if yes why ?

> My motivation for asking this question was due to the fact that in coordinate geometry the slope of perpendicular lines is -1 , so for m= 0 slope the m= infinity correponds to it , so in that case infinity * 0  =  -1 (valid). So i was thinking why cannot there exists a situation here too possible ?

Comment: $f'(f(x))$ is a real number. Infinity is not a real number. A real number multiplied by zero is zero.

Comment: @YiFan Why not put that exact text in an answer post?

Comment: @YiFan but f(x) can take infinity value which is in its range too , so why cannot the same be said for f'(y),  y =f(x)  ?

Comment: And actually my motivation for asking this question was due to the fact that in coordinate geometry the product of slope of perpendicular lines is -1 , so for m= 0 slope the m= infinity correponds to it , so in that case infinity * 0  =  -1 (valid). @YiFan

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer $f(x)$ cannot take infinite values. The notation $(0,\infty)$ means the set of positive real numbers, and infinity is not a real number.

Comment: More generally, $(a,b)$ refers to the set of all real $x$ so that $a<x<b$. Note the strict inequalities so that neither $a$ nor $b$ is in the set.

Comment: Understood that thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothesis is that $f: (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is a continuously differentiable function --- that means $f':(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ exists and is well-defined. So $f'(x)$ for any positive real number $x$ is a real number, as $\infty$ is not in the codomain $\mathbb R$.

So, $f'(f(x))f'(x)=2$ implies neither $f'(f(x))$ nor $f'(x)$ is zero.

Comment: I understood just one query how does f'(x) exists tells that its codomain is (0, infinity) ? I can see that domain is indeed (0 ,infinity) as in that its f(x) is being defined so naturally f'(x) too .

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Oops, sorry. The codomain of $f'$ should be $\mathbb R$, since we don't know that $f'(x)$ is positive for all $x$. But anyways, it is true that $\infty$ is not in the codomain.

Comment: Thanks a lot , can you also clear the motivation problem which i said above ? I mean in striaight lines product of perpendicular slopes is -1 , does it fails when either is zero ? Or its just by chance giving the correct value of other slopes as infinity/-infinity ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer It's not really by chance, it does make sense to say that the gradient of a vertical line is infinite, despite it not being a real number. It is indeed, in some sense, the case that the product of perpendicular slopes is $-1$ even in the case of infinite gradients.  I guess you can say that real numbers don't describe the gradient of lines very well --- it is more "complete" in a sense to describe slopes using angles (e.g. relative to the horizontal). In this case there is no problem with infinity for vertical lines.

Comment: Thanks wonderful explanation :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Just for completion, the reason we usually use gradient instead of angle is that angles are connected to concrete drawings and lines in a plane. If you want something that describes the slope of a _function_, then angle doesn't cut it, because the graph of the same function can be drawn in many different ways, with different scales along the $x$ and $y$ axes, which can drastically change any angle that isn't $0^\circ$ or $90^\circ$. So if you want a number that describes the slope of the function regardless of coordinate system, gradient is better.

Comment: Pretty nice thanks @Arthur